# function holomorphic on an annulus with real part bounded by z at infinity reduces has limit

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

> > Let $f$ be a function holomorphic at $1<|z|<\infty$ and $z^{-1}\operatorname{Re}f(z)\to 0$ as $z\to \infty$. Prove that $\lim_{z\to \infty} f(z)\in \mathbb{C}$ exists.

I want to prove this by first showing function holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ with the same condition reduces to a constant but don't know how to proceed. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You certainly cannot show that $f$ is constant from the given conditions. After all, $f(z)=\frac1z$ is okay. -- What I can easily see is that the singularity of $f$ at $\infty$ is either removable (our goal) or essential, but certainly not a pole ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_nz^n$ be its Laurent expansion in $1<|z|<\infty.$ Then 
\begin{align}
&u(Re^{i\theta })=\operatorname{Re}f(Re^{i\theta })\\
&=\operatorname{Re}a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\left(\operatorname{Re}a_nR^n+\operatorname{Re}a_{-n}R^{-n}\right)\cos n\theta -\left(\operatorname{Im}a_nR^n-\operatorname{Im}a_{-n}R^{-n}\right)\sin n\theta \right]
\end{align}

Therefore for $n\ge 1$, we have 
\begin{align}
&\operatorname{Re}a_nR^n+\operatorname{Re}a_{-n}R^{-n} =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(Re^{i\theta })\cos n\theta \,d\theta,      \\
&\operatorname{Im}a_nR^n-\operatorname{Im}a_{-n}R^{-n}=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(re^{i\theta })\sin n\theta \, d\theta. 
\end{align}
Dividing by $R^n$ we have 
\begin{align}
&\operatorname{Re}a_n+\operatorname{Re}a_{-n}R^{-2n} =\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{u(Re^{i\theta })}{R^n}\cos n\theta \,d\theta, \tag{1}     \\     
&\operatorname{Im}a_n-\operatorname{Im}a_{-n}R^{-2n}=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{u(re^{i\theta })}{R^n}\sin n\theta \, d\theta.\tag{2}
\end{align}
By the condition $z^{-1} \operatorname{Re}f(z)\to 0$ as $z\to \infty$, we have $$\frac{1}{R}u(Re^{i\theta })\to 0 \:\;(R\to \infty).
$$
Tending $R\to \infty$ in $(1),(2)$ we have 
$$
\operatorname{Re}a_n =0,\quad \operatorname{Im}a_n=0,
$$
that is, $a_n=0$ for $n\ge 1.$
Thus $$
f(z)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_{-n}}{z^n}.$$
We see that $\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z)$ exists.